# magento 2 multiple values drop down dependencies?

Tags: magento2, drop-downs, dependency

in magento 2 i have a drop down with the options 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6

when we  if '1' Test-1 and Custom-1 text fields want to show.
as well if i choose '2' Test-2 and Custom-2 text fields want to show respectively.

Please find the screenshots as shown below

[image]

[image]

Please suggest me and help me how to achieve this in magento 2 admin end?
thanks

Comment: Are you trying to do this in store -> configuration ?

Comment: No @Ramkishan i am trying to do from my custom module at admin form